# slim rest api work fine on localhost but it returning error 500 on shared hosting?

Tags: php, rest, api, slim, shared-hosting

I have developed an application using angualar and php with slim and it works fine in localhost , but slim rest api showing error code 500 on shared hosting, How to solve this issue  ?

when i try to check it showing below message

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@demoems.aaaaa.com
>   and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: You need to check the server logs. Even shared hosts provide these in the control panel, but if yours doesn't then you should call the host and have them tell you the error. Nobody can tell you what your 500 error is

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache 
you must create .htaccess file with this configuration

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Also you must config your shared hosting apache config file

Find **var/www/** Block 
and change 
this

```
AllowOverride none
```

To

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: i am using shared hosting service and there is no folder like var/www

Comment: its not a folder

Comment: its a path on your apache.conf file on your hosting find it and find this block

Comment: i search in all files and in  dont found apache.conf  file in my cpanel

Comment: Search with your company name or ask them to help you in finding it

Comment: Search with your company name ? example ?

Comment: Which one of  the  shared hosting companies you use

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by setting folder ,file permission to 755,644